# Issues with displaying validation messages with Nested Forms (Rails 2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a nested form, and for the most part it is working great.  The only issue that I have is in displaying validiation errors.

Consider the following object relationship:  a Project has_many :tasks, a Task has_many :assignments

if a validation error occurs on an assignment, with `<%=project_form.error_messages %>` It displays **Task Assignment Due Date is invalid**  I would rather it just read **Due Date is invalid** or **Jon's Math Homework Due Date is invalid**.

Does this support exist?  Do I need to roll my own? Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application those errors didn't has "Task Assignment" part. I don't remember that I had changed something somewhere. You can try writing your own method to display errors. You can get to them using:

```
@project.errors
```

or using form builder:

```
project_form.object.errors
```

Firstly try to just inspect them:

```
# in view
<%= @project.errors.inspect %>
```

It will allow you to take a look on it's structure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, couldn't figure out where the Task Assignment part came from either.  So I took your advice and rolled my own.  I found that the exposed errors where not sufficient. So I added the following an initializer: `class ActiveRecord::Errors

  def errors_hash
    return @errors
  end

end`

Worked like a charm.